# Slicing pandas dataframe with list of list with columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a huge dataframe, of which I iteratively need to slice some different columns.
All columns to slice, I have in a list, like

```
[col1, col2, col3]
[col2, col3, col4]
[col1, col2, col4]
```

etc etc.

What I do now, is I loop through the list of columns and then use loc to select all the columns, like

```
df.loc[:,columns]
```

(where columns is a row of the above list, for instance `[col1, col2, col3]`)

This works, but like I mentioned, I have a huge dataframe, and the list of columns is a lot larger than 3.

Is there any way to vectorize this operation and do it all at once, while still getting the different, seperate results? I do not want 1 dataframe, but a different slice of the dataframe for each seperate combination of columns.

EDIT:

This is an example of what I use now, and it works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Col2':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'Col3':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'Col4':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
  
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

cols_to_select = np.empty(3, dtype=np.object)
cols_to_select[0] = ['Col1', 'Col3']
cols_to_select[1] = ['Col2', 'Col3']
cols_to_select[2] = ['Col3', 'Col4']

for col in cols_to_select:
    print(df.loc[:, col])
```

Output:

```
    Col1  Col3
0    Tom    20
1   nick    21
2  krish    19
3   jack    18
   Col2  Col3
0    20    20
1    21    21
2    19    19
3    18    18
   Col3  Col4
0    20    20
1    21    21
2    19    19
3    18    18
```

The problem is, the slicing of the columns happens three times in this example, in the for loop. Can this be made more efficient - keeping the same results?

Comment: Can you explain more how is filtered lists by `df.loc[:,columns]` ? Also is possible add some [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here 2-3 columns with filtering and expected output DataFrame with input data?

Comment: how do you want to hold the results? in a dictionary or list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not worth an answer, just a comment, but: in this case, you are probably overthinking it - in any case, a simple list comprehension is probably sufficient...

```
In [1]: from pandas import util                                                                                                                                                                                                          
In [10]: util.testing.K = 20                                                                                                                                                                                                             
In [11]: df = util.testing.makeDataFrame() 
In [13]: %timeit df[['A', 'G', 'M', 'N']]                                                                                                                                                                                                
289 µs ± 7.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So you could simply do something like

```
df_list = [df[cols] for cols in col_selectors]
```

and that's probably about as fast as you can do.

Why this works (and what kind of vectorization you want to do): basically, pandas is a list of numpy series; each series is a column (which is why columns have datatypes, not rows). So extracting a list of columns is really just grabbing a list of the pointers to each column's series that you want - a fairly cheap operation. This is different than grabbing a subset of rows - to do that, pandas (via numpy) has to extract some of the values from the series (array) and concatenate them into a new series. So grabbing a set of *rows* would be very expensive, while grabbing a subset of *columns* is cheap.

(note that the transpose operation seems to be fairly cheap as well, so sometimes transposing a DataFrame and then extracting columns is quite a bit faster than extracting various sets of rows, but definitely YMMV here :)

Edit: For a larger example, here is for 10000 columns of 10000 entries each. It does take longer, but not dramatically so - I'm actually not sure why it takes longer, I didn't expect it to this much, possibly the generation of the dataframe from the list of series is impacted by this.

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000, 10000))                                                                                                                                                                                  
In [5]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[5]: 
....
[10000 rows x 10000 columns]
In [6]: %timeit df[[2000,3000,4000,5000]]                                                                                                                                                                                                
512 µs ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit df[[1,4,9,16,25,32,200,300,400]]                                                                                                                                                                                         
968 µs ± 21.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Can you give some test in Dataframe with 1000 rows and 1000 columns for explain `So grabbing a set of rows would be very expensive, while grabbing a subset of columns is cheap.` ? I think here you are wrong.

Comment: Added an example... it does have some effect, but it's very sublinear wrt the size of the dataframe itself, more related to how many columns you are extracting.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000, 10000))    



In [92]: %timeit df[[1,4,9,16,25,32,200,300,400]]
2.93 ms ± 61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [93]: %timeit df.loc[[1,4,9,16,25,32,200,300,400]]
712 µs ± 10.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: You are wrong, faster is select by rows, not by columns, test above.

Comment: interesting... will have to look at that more, i am not an expert or heavy pandas user, but that does not match my interaction with frames in the past.... if that's true, maybe some things i tried before will work better now...